# Tengo un problema para realizar un filter en React

Tags: javascript, html5, reactjs

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto de una concesionaria de autos y en el cual tengo una sección para buscar marca, modelo, año del vehículo, etc.
Los que les muestro es un componente llamado "Filter", lo que quiero hacer es que en el Dropdown de "Marcas" al seleccionarlo me traiga su respectivo modelo de dicha
marca en el otro dropdown de "Modelo".
Lo que estuve tratando de hacer es que al hacer clic en dicha marca me traiga el "ID".
Estoy trabajando React + laravel

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
    import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
    import axios from "axios";
    
    import Navbr from "../navbar/Navbr";
    import Footer from "../footer/Footer";
    
    import "./filter.css";
    import { Dropdown, DropdownButton } from "react-bootstrap";
    
    const baseUrl = "http://periplo-cars.test";
    
    function Filter() {
        const [marca, setMarca] = useState([]);
        const [modelo, setModelo] = useState([]);
    
        useEffect(() => {
            const traerMarcas = async () => {
                const url = `${baseUrl}/api/filtro/marcas`;
                const result = await axios.get(url);
                /*      console.log(result.data); */
    
                setMarca(result.data);
            };
            traerMarcas();
        }, []);
        console.log(marca);
    
        useEffect(() => {
            const traerModelos = async () => {
                const url = `${baseUrl}/api/filtro/modelos`;
                const result = await axios.get(url);
                /*       console.log(result.data);  */
    
                setModelo(result.data);
            };
            traerModelos();
        }, []);
    
        return (
            <>
                <div className=" imgheader">
                    <Navbr />
                    <div className="filter">
                        <div class="form">
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                name="text"
                                autocomplete="off"
                                required
                            />
                            <label class="label-name">
                                <span
                                    class="content-name"
                                    style={{ color: "#fff" }}
                                >
                                    Buscar Auto
                                </span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
    
                    <div className="dropdown">
                        <DropdownButton variant="light" title="Marca">
                            {marca.map((car) => {
                                return (
                                    <Dropdown.Item key={car.id} value={car.id}>
                                        {car.marca}
                                    </Dropdown.Item>
                                );
                            })}
                        </DropdownButton>
    
                        <DropdownButton variant="light" title="Modelo">
                            {modelo.map((car) => {
                                return (
                                    <Dropdown.Item key={car.id}>
                                        {car.modelo_mas_variante}
                                    </Dropdown.Item>
                                );
                            })}
    

    
   
    
                        </DropdownButton>
    
                        <Dropdown>
                            <Dropdown.Toggle variant="light" id="dropdown-basic">
                                Año
                            </Dropdown.Toggle>
    
                            <Dropdown.Menu>
                                <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-1">
                                    Action
                                </Dropdown.Item>
                                <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-2">
                                    Another action
                                </Dropdown.Item>
                                <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-3">
                                    Something else
                                </Dropdown.Item>
                            </Dropdown.Menu>
                        </Dropdown>
    
                        <Dropdown>
                            <Dropdown.Toggle variant="light" id="dropdown-basic">
                                Motor
                            </Dropdown.Toggle>
    
                            <Dropdown.Menu>
                                <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-1">
                                    Action
                                </Dropdown.Item>
                                <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-2">
                                    Another action
                                </Dropdown.Item>
                                <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-3">
                                    Something else
                                </Dropdown.Item>
                            </Dropdown.Menu>
                        </Dropdown>
                        <Dropdown>
                            <Dropdown.Toggle variant="light" id="dropdown-basic">
                                Vendedor
                            </Dropdown.Toggle>
    
                            <Dropdown.Menu>
                                <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-1">
                                    Action
                                </Dropdown.Item>
                                <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-2">
                                    Another action
                                </Dropdown.Item>
                                <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-3">
                                    Something else
                                </Dropdown.Item>
                            </Dropdown.Menu>
                        </Dropdown>
                        <Dropdown>
                            <Dropdown.Toggle variant="light" id="dropdown-basic">
                                Combustible
                            </Dropdown.Toggle>
    
                            <Dropdown.Menu>
                                <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-1">
                                    Action
                                </Dropdown.Item>
                                <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-2">
                                    Another action
                                </Dropdown.Item>
                                <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-3">
                                    Something else
                                </Dropdown.Item>
                            </Dropdown.Menu>
                        </Dropdown>
                        <Dropdown>
                            <Dropdown.Toggle variant="light" id="dropdown-basic">
                                Rango de Precio
                            </Dropdown.Toggle>
    
                            <Dropdown.Menu>
                                <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-1">
                                    Action
                                </Dropdown.Item>
                                <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-2">
                                    Another action
                                </Dropdown.Item>
                                <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-3">
                                    Something else
                                </Dropdown.Item>
                            </Dropdown.Menu>
                        </Dropdown>
                        <Dropdown>
                            <Dropdown.Toggle variant="light" id="dropdown-basic">
                                Ubicación
                            </Dropdown.Toggle>
    
                            <Dropdown.Menu>
                                <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-1">
                                    Action
                                </Dropdown.Item>
                                <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-2">
                                    Another action
                                </Dropdown.Item>
                                <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-3">
                                    Something else
                                </Dropdown.Item>
                            </Dropdown.Menu>
                        </Dropdown>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <Footer />
            </>
        );
    }
    
    export default Filter;
    
    if (document.getElementById("filtro")) {
        ReactDOM.render(<Filter />, document.getElementById("filtro"));
    }
```

Comment: Creo que la solución mas fácil es pasarle el ID a tu función de la marca o lo que sea que estes buscando y utilizando el metodo de javascript filter, filtras el ID de lo que estas buscando. Cuando vos utilizas filter tenes que comparar el ID que estas pasando en tu función con el ID en la API y haces que se filtre todo elemento con un ID distinto al que estas buscando, entonces te quedara un array con solo ese elemento.

Comment: Tienes que crear una función que maneje el cambio de tu dropdown, con el evento  onChange, en esa función obtienes el el valor seleccionado y haces un llamado a tu API, la manera en la que lo haces actualmente solo hace el fetch cuando el componente se monta.